# Can the ODP.NET Managed Driver and Unmanaged Driver be run in parallel on the same machine

Tags: visual-studio-2017, odp.net, odac

I need to install and run a legacy piece of software (circa 2014) implementation utilising the unmanaged driver from ODP.NET, unfortunately corporate software has been updated, replacing the unmanaged driver with the managed driver.

Is it possible to run the managed and unmanaged driver on the same machine?  I also need to source the unmanaged driver (old ODAC install set), but I can only seem to find the managed driver on the Oracle site.  I am using Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they can run in parallel. ODP.NET Managed Provider is self contained and doesn't interact with other installations. I would recommend that you get it from nuget.

It is multiple unmanaged ODP.NET installations that gets tricky, but that still can be done.

You can get the unmanaged provider here:
https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/dotnet-odacdeploy-downloads.html

The first section uses the Oracle installer and the second section is a xcopy version where you copy some files. I would recommend the xcopy version.

Comment: *"I would recommend that you get it from nuget."* contrary, I would reccomentd to go to oracle site and download ODP Developer pack for Visual Studio which will integrate tools and provider, etc

Comment: Ok... So now I have installed ODAC version 18.3.  This did not work with the legacy software.  Checking the versions of Oracle.DataAccess.dll

ODAC 18.3 Version - 2.122.18.3
Legacy Software compiled against Version - 2.112.1.0

Comment: Having not resolved the problem I would now like to remove ODAC 18.3, however there is no deinstall option in the Oracle Installer, and there is no uninstall batch file with the download package either.  How can I ensure that I remove all the ODAC 18.3 software?  Is it a case of simply using gacutil to unregister the dlls (2.x and 4) and then simply delete the folder structure.

Comment: Its a while (a few years) since I had to deal with Oracle uninstall issues and I would have thought they would have made an effort to improve matters, but alas apparently not.  Any advice?  Both in terms of cleaning up my machine and resoving the original issue.

Comment: Hi Paul, it depends on how you installed it in the first place. If you used the MSI installer, check the add/remove programs in the control panel to uninstall it. If you used Oracle's Java based installer (OUI) there should be an item in the windows Start menu to run the installer.

Comment: Hi Paul, you can find 11.2 ODP.NET here: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/dotnet-odacdeploy-downloads.html

Answer (score 1):

**Unmanaged** - you need to install Oracle client of the same architecture (x86/x64) as your app/host; and version. For example, if your machine is x64, your code compiled to "prefer 32 bit", you need x86 version of unmanaged. Or, if you have x64 machine with code built for AnyCPU without "prefer 32 bit", you will need x64 version of unmanaged.

**Managed** will work on the same machine and will not conflict with unmanaged in any way. You can download from Oracle the ODP Developer package for Visual Studio and this will install integration tools, managed provider, etc. Keep in mind - Certain versions of managed support or don't support specific versions of Oracle database